# ABRSM Practical Musicianship Exam - Do I need an accompanist?

Tags: abrsm, exam

I am planning to take the ABRSM practical musicianship exam grade 5 in London this year, for euphonium.

I have read through the rules myself, but it does NOT seem to require me to bring an accompanist.

However, I would like to make sure, so I ask here for anyone who has done it before.

Update : I got the confirmation that you do NOT need an accompaniment fo the Practical Musicianship Exam 5+.

Comment: The comment thread seems to have been deleted, but there was a good deal of confusion about the exam the poster was referring to. The ABRSM "Practical Musicianship" exam is not the standard instrumental exam. Grade 5 Practical Musicianship can be taken as an an alternative to Grade 5 Music Theory as an entry requirement for taking Performance Grades 6 to 8.  It is described at https://www.abrsm.org/en-gb/other-assessments/practical-musicianship and its syllabus is at https://www.abrsm.org/sites/default/files/2023-09/praccomplete10.pdf

Comment: @JamesMartin You should turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not having done this particular exam, but reading through the syllabus, it appears any accompaniment will be done by the examiner. Other parts of the exam will be solo.

A clue as to what instrument OP is using would be interesting, but not essential in answering this question.

A quick call to ABRSM themselves would be appropriate and simple - I've found them to be quite accommodating with queries in the past.

**EDIT** - having actually contacted ABRSM, they verified that in fact yes, the candidate **does** have to bring their own accompanist - who can be their teacher - but that person can only be in the room for the time they're accompanying.

Reading the syllabus on their website is confusing, but there's the definitive answer, now!

**RE-EDIT**!!Still awaiting a reply (by email) from AB, but reading the practical **Musicianship** syllabus, there will only be the examiner present, who will play - on piano, presumably, anything which needs playing. There is no accompaniment mentioned in this particular exam. Not to be confused with solo instrument which will most likely need an accompanist, as the examiner will be busy doing what they're there for - examining. Apologies for the change of mind - but a good question, which, actually, teacher should have provided an answer to by now.

***RE-RE-EDIT*** - finally had the answer from AB - the examiner WILL accompany. Straight from the horse's mouth... Thank you AB!

Comment: I am going to play the euphonium. Ok, so it seems that I do not need to bring an accompanist... But anyway, I will call them to check again. Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this apply to *any* grade?  I would think for a higher grade that has many selections, would it be fair to expect the examiner to sight read (or prepare) to play moderate to difficult accompaniment?  A relevant question: does a candidate have the option of bringing their own accompanist?

Comment: @Keith Update the question with ABRSM's reply!

Comment: -1. This answer is incorrect. The examinee supplies the accompanist, and examiners will not accompany. See the ABRSM website for regulations.

Comment: I am confused by the edit. Was the ABRSM person you spoke to on the phone definitely aware that you were asking specifically about the Practical Musicianship exam? Which of the activities involved in the Grade 5 exam listed on p.93 of https://www.abrsm.org/sites/default/files/2023-09/praccomplete10.pdf is the accompanist supposed to be involved in?

Comment: @JamesMartin - I think there is some confusion between standard *instrumental* exams, which for solo instruments will obviously need an accompanist, and Practical musicianSHIP exams, where most likely the examiner would provide any accompaniment needed. In the LCM exams  gtr and bass)I used to host, any accompaniment was always done by the examiner, but that's a different board. I have re-posed the question, and await the answer.

Comment: The answer now looks very confusing with the no/yes/no/yes edits. I suggest deleting everything except for the information in the very last paragraph.

Comment: @PiedPiper - just thought I'd leave it for a bit - showing the trouble some of us go to..! Yes, it does need re-re-re-editing. Get round to it soon. Love to know how te 2 dvers came to their conclusions, soon after the 1st part (correct) was written, though.

Comment: I've reverted my DV. I was as confused as everybody else was.

Comment: @PiedPiper - thank you for that - but - as you probably know by now, I'd have appreciated a reason in the comments as to your original reasons. That way, we all know where we're coming from. Hence all my moans about unsupported dvs.

Comment: James Martin had already supplied the reason.

Answer (score 3):

According to the ABRSM website:

For in-person exams:

> Applicants must make sure that **candidates bring their own accompanist**. The candidate’s teacher may accompany; **the examiner will not accompany under any circumstances** (except in the Prep Test). The accompanist may stay in the exam room only while accompanying. (https://www.abrsm.org/en-gb/about-our-exams/exam-regulations, under Regulations -> Instrumental and singing exams -> paragraph l; emphasis mine.)

For digital exams:

> Applicants must make sure that candidates perform with a live accompaniment, which should be organised by them. The candidate’s teacher may accompany.  (ibid., section q.)

See also sections aa, bb, and cc. The last of these mentions that a separate copy of the score for the examiner is not required.

Comment: Yes. That's when you are playing an actual music piece like a concerto. Practical Musicianship is not like that, according to the syllabus.

Comment: Surely, I don't need accompaniment when I am doing transposition?

Comment: I feel this answer is based on the good old instrumental exams, for solo instruments The Musicianship exam is fairly new, and has quite a different slat on what happens. There is no time where the candidate will perform rehearsed pieces with  the player with whom they've practised.

Comment: See my re-re-edit for the definitive on this one. Always worth asking the 'powers that be'.